# Why Wont my program wait for an amount of time

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy_Jump : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpHeight;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpDelay;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Jump ();
    }

    void Jump(){
        StartCoroutine ("Wait");
        rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));

    }

    IEnumerator Wait(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (jumpDelay);
        Debug.Log ("waiting");
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

I seem to be having an issue where it is not waiting for any amount of time. I have also entered a set number into the `waitForSeconds` function but it still does not delay anything. I do not know of any other way nor have a found any other way via online search to delay the function.

Comment: The courotine does not affect your rb.AddForce line. A courotine cand delay only the code inside it, and Jump() is not called from the courotine but from update which is called every frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving where you add the force in the coroutine. And when you call a coroutine in the Update function it will basically call a new coroutine each frame so you need some way of knowing you're already waiting.

```
bool isWaiting;
IEnumerator Wait(){
    isWaiting = true;

    Debug.Log ("waiting");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (jumpDelay);

    rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));

    isWaiting = false;
}
```

So you would check if `isWaiting` is false before calling a new coroutine

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!isWaiting) 
        Jump ();
}
```

You should probably use `InvokeRepeating` if you want to do something every certain amount of time. Calling a coroutine from the Update function is not a good idea.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

    InvokeRepeating("Wait", 0, jumpDelay);
}

void Wait(){

    rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));
}
```

[InvokeRepeating Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried that as well and it still will not wait for any amount of time.

Comment: @Camman012 You also have to remove the `rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));` in the `Jump` function.